# Graphic Location in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

I am trying insert an image that is loaded from a directory location. Most suggestions to resolve this involve inserting a picture object, right clicking it, selecting "Format Object", selecting the "Picture" tab, clicking the formula button next to "Graphic Location" and from there telling it where to select image from.

My problem is that the version of Crystal Reports I'm using (10.2.3600.0) doesn't seem to have the "Graphic Location" option (I've got another project using more recent version - 13.0.2000.0 - which does).

My question is: Is there similar functionality in the older version but reached in a different way? I don't want to have to update/change entire application to use more recent CR version  (and risk something breaking) just to do this small change.

*Edited to add: The more recent CR version is in a VS2010 app, older one is in VS2005 app. Not sure if it could be functionality inherited from VS version. I doubt it but prob worth mentioning.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have VS 2005 any longer, but I do remember that all you had to do in order to insert a picture from file was to right click on an empty section of the report you were editing/creating, choose Insert -> Picture and a file dialog box would open. You chose your picture file (only certain file formats were supported) and then you could drag a box around the report and left-click when you had the desired location. That would insert the picture into the report and then you could right-click on it and format it.

Hope that helps,

Chris

EDIT: According to SAP there is a way of achieving what you are after. There is a sample you can download [here](https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100006252822008E/net_win_smpl.exe). The way you are trying to do it is only possible for Crystal Reports XI R2 and Crystal Reports 2008. [Here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1086381) is the link to the post at SAP.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can insert an image no problem. The problem is linking to an image in a directory (so that the image can be replaced in the folder and picked up by the report on the fly, no need to alter report to alter image)

Comment: That's what I figured, functionality not available in the version I'm using. I'll have a look at alternative methods like the one in your link. Cheers.